# File `MinionPro.sty' not found

Tags: xetex, packages

I have latex (.tex) files that I want to work with on Windows 10, but I received an error from latex, the error is: `` File `MinionPro.sty 'not found. ``

It seems to me that I don't have the MinionPro.sty package, I looked for it all over the internet but I found nothing, please if you have an answer, please help me find this package or contact me give an IDE name which contains by default all latex packages
thank you for your help sir / madam

Comment: Minion refers to a font which is afaik a commercial font. Have you tried using a different font?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu, you can use the command

```
sudo apt search minionpro
```

For me, this gives the output

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
texlive-fonts-extra/focal,focal,now 2019.202000218-1 all [installed]
  TeX Live: Additional fonts
```

Suggesting that if you download the package texlive-fonts-extra, you will automatically download the minionpro font.

I'm not sure about the Windows equivalent, but maybe you can just look for an additional fonts package all the same.

EDIT: is this useful to you? https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro

Comment: Hi ,i have recentely install latex in ubuntu but nothing new , i have the same problem.the problem with moniopro is .otf file needed to install the moniopro package , i don't have this .otf file , can you help me please

Comment: This file https://github.com/henrikgit/MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub/blob/master/mpro-installation-guide-miktex.pdf suggets you check your Adobe Profile folder to find the .otf fonts in \Resource\Font

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK MionionPro was made public domain domain by Adobe years ago but recent versions of Adobe do not have it in their Resource folder.  It's still possible to download earlier versions from e.g. https://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/
and copy the .otf files (MinionPro-BoldIt.otf etc) into a suitable local folder like
\texmf-local\fonts\opentype

Once they are there, doubleclick on each to install them into Windows.